# How do i make the image centered relative to the nav bar after the animation is finished?

Tags: html, css

Im trying to have the logo centered relative to the nav bar.  I need to make it responsive to different screen sizes (see photos)[[Laptop and Mobile views of the site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9tjt.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GA3X.png)

Note: there is an animation where it starts off screen left and moves to the center of the screen.  I cant edit the 'left' property of the .calLogo selector because doing so messes up the animation.  Here is the code i have so far:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>DShop</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <nav>
            <a href="./index.html">Home</a>
            <a href="./about.html">About</a>
            <a href="">Reviews</a>
            <a href="./order.html">Order Now</a>
            <div class="animation start-home"></div> 
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="carLogo-container">
        <img src="images/DDimage2.jpeg" alt="carLogo" class="carLogo">
    </div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

//CSS

/* -------nav bar for all pages------ */
nav {
    margin: 20px auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 470px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #34495e;
    border-radius: 8px;
    font-size: 0;
}

nav a {
    line-height: 50px;
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: Arial Rounded MT Bold;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
}

nav .animation {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    transition: all .5s ease 0s;
    border-radius: 8px;
}
a:nth-child(1) {
    width: 100px;
}
a:nth-child(2) {
    width: 110px;
}
a:nth-child(3) {
    width: 100px;
}
a:nth-child(4) {
    width: 160px;
}
nav .start-home, a:nth-child(1):hover~.animation {
    width: 100px;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #1e90ff;
}
nav .start-home, a:nth-child(2):hover~.animation {
    width: 110px;
    left: 100px;
    background-color: #1e90ff;
}
nav .start-home, a:nth-child(3):hover~.animation {
    width: 100px;
    left: 210px;
    background-color: #1e90ff;
}
nav .start-home, a:nth-child(4):hover~.animation {
    width: 160px;
    left: 310px;
    background-color: #1e90ff;
}

/* ------- Home Page ------- */

body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background: #bfc2c4;
}

.carLogo {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    left: -100px;
    animation: move-right 1s ease forwards;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}

@keyframes move-right {
    100% {
        left: calc(60% - 100px);
    }
}
```

1. Ive tried editing the 'left' property of the .carLogo class, but that messes up the animation
2. Changed the 'display' on .carLogo to 'flex' and 'inline-block' doesnt do anything.
3. Editing the @keyframes move-right selector from 50% to 60% makes it centered on the laptop screen, but i need it to be centered on all screens.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
.carLogo-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.carLogo {
  position: relative; 
}
```

Comment: when i add flex the image ends on the right of the page in full screen, and kinda in the middle on the mobile screen